# code ERESOLVE when running the command npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

I'm new to ReactJS and tried to run a code in VS Code using **npm install** command and this error pops up:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: diq@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next
npm ERR! react-bootstrap-table-next@"^4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-29T06_50_12_261Z-debug-0.log
```

Kindly help to resolve this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that `react-bootstrap-table-next` does not yet support react 17. https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/1503